# Combining two expressions into a pipeline

Tags: c#, expression, combinators

Let us say I have the following two expressions:

```
Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TNested>>> collectionSelector;
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TNested>, TNested>> elementSelector;
```

Is there a way to "combine" these in order to form the below: (?)

```
Expression<Func<T, TNested>> selector;
```

EDIT:

Performance is very critical, so I would appreciate an optimal solution with very little overhead, if possible.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
static Expression<Func<A, C>> Foo<A, B, C>(
Expression<Func<B, C>> f,
Expression<Func<A, B>> g)
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(A));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<A, C>>(
        Expression.Invoke(f, Expression.Invoke(g, x)), x);
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot access to computer ( it is bad solution in performance terms). Actually, I think that you can optimize code via call Expression.

Another way seems like that(usage auxiliary function):

```
Func<A, C> Foo<A,B,C>(Func<B, C> f, Func<A, B> g)
{ 
    return (A x) => f(g(x));
}
```

Then you should create pipeline Expression via call Expression with Foo function. Like that pseudo code:

```
   var expr1 = get expresstion<B,C> 
   var expr2 = get Expression<A, B>
   var foo = get method info of Foo method 
   specialize method with generic types A, B, C (via make generic method)
    return Expression.Call(foo, expr1, expr2);
```

Comment: I modified answer

Comment: The second proposed solution creates delegates and anonymous objects, which I would say is not very good in terms of performance.. or am I missing something?

Comment: It will generate calling function with needed arguments, instead usage of dynamic invoking. dynamic invoke is too slow

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, but I am looking for something in the expression level which does not incur anonymous object instantiation. I gave you an upvote anyway since this is a solution. Just not the one I am after.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use `ExpressionVisitor` to replace the parameter in right expression with the whole left expression, in other words, embed the left one in the right one.

Expression visitor will be quite simple, add needed data to constructor, override one method and that's all.

```
internal sealed class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _searched;
    private readonly Expression _replaced;

    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression searched, Expression replaced)
    {
        if (searched == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searched));
        if (replaced == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaced));

        _searched = searched;
        _replaced = replaced;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node == _searched)
            return _replaced;

        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

It can be quite easily extended to handle collections of expressions in the constructor, but I kept it short.

Now, you just need to use it on the expression bodies and construct new lambda.

```
private static Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> Merge<TIn, TInter, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TInter>> left, Expression<Func<TInter, TOut>> right)
{
    var merged = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(right.Parameters[0], left.Body).Visit(right.Body);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(merged, left.Parameters[0]);

    return lambda;
}
```

I tested it on this code:

```
Expression<Func<string, int>> l = s => s.Length + 5;
Expression<Func<int, string>> r = i => i.ToString() + " something";

var merged = Merge(l, r);

var res = merged.Compile()("test");
```

and the result is as expected: `9 something`.

EDIT:
If performance is your concern, why are you using expressions instead of plain `Func`s? Then you could just invoke one after another. Are the expression trees later analyzed?

Comment: I don't know why this solution has no UP. This is it! This is perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression<Func<TSourceType, TFinalType>> ChainExpressions<TSourceType, TIntermediaryType, TFinalType>(
        Expression<Func<TSourceType, TIntermediaryType>> firstExpression,
        Expression<Func<TIntermediaryType, TFinalType>> secondExpression
    )
    {
        var sourceInput = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSourceType));
        var expressionForIntermediaryValue = Expression.Invoke(firstExpression, sourceInput);
        var expressionToGetTypedIntermediaryValue = Expression.Convert(expressionForIntermediaryValue, typeof(TIntermediaryType));

        var expressionForFinalValue = Expression.Invoke(secondExpression, expressionToGetTypedIntermediaryValue);
        var expressionToGetTypedFinalValue = Expression.Convert(expressionForFinalValue, typeof(TFinalType));

        var finalOutputExpression = Expression.Lambda(expressionToGetTypedFinalValue, sourceInput);
        return (Expression<Func<TSourceType, TFinalType>>)finalOutputExpression;
    }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)