# Join/chain two expressions

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

How can I combine/join/chain two Expressions into one?

E.g

```
Expression<Func<A,object>> first = x => x.B.C;
Expression<Func<C,object>> second = x => x.D.E;
```

Where the end result would be equal to this:

```
Expression<Func<A,object>> result = x => x.B.C.D.E;
```

The property accessors in the above example have been written using class names for readability only.

By using the approach explained here: [Combining two expressions into a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696361/combining-two-expressions-into-a-pipeline) the results are the same but the expressions differ.

Is it possible to join so that the result equals x.B.C.D.E instead of Invoke's?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Expression<Func<A,C>>` then?  Otherwise you don't know that `first` actually returns a `C` that can be used in `second`.

Comment: If you need to join the two results see msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(A));
var i1 = Expression.Invoke(first, param);
var i1Convert = Expression.Convert(i1, typeof(C));

var i2 = Expression.Invoke(second, i1Convert);
var i2Convert = Expression.Convert(i2, typeof(object));

var result = Expression.Lambda(i2Convert , param);
```

You should convert to C, because you assume, that first Expression gives `C` back, not `object`.